# Screen shrinks when keyboard appearing

Tags: android, xamarin.android, screen, soft-keyboard, shrink

I have the following screen on Android Application:

[image]

When I press the SearchView, the screen shrinks like that:

[image]

I want the screen to stay still (as in the first image) when keyboard appears. 
Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <SearchView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_border"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchViewCustomers" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/customersRecyclerView"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="Нов"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried the solutions for that found in internet but they are not working for me maybe because they are for Android(Java). If there is a way to do than in xml not in C# code it's much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the screen to stay still (as in the first image) when keyboard appears.

If you don't want the screen to auto adjust, you can set `WindowSoftInputMode` of your activity to `SoftInput.AdjustNothing` like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "Sample", MainLauncher = true,WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustNothing)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    ...
}
```